# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in Python with pyFCM - Client registration

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build a simple "Hello World" type app that includes push notifications (via FCM) in python using kivy and pyFCM.

i'm having trouble finding a way in python to create a "device registration token" as described here: "https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client"

Is there a reasonable way to do this in python or should i start looking into building my app with Android Studio?

Comment: pyFCM seems to be used for sending FCM messages to Android and iOS clients. The device registration token is generated on the client side and then sent to the server (pyFCM in this case). So it's not python or building it into your app it's both.

Comment: yep this turned out to be correct. I was hoping for a pure python way, but there doesnt appear to be one. Ended up just using Android Studio to build/design the app and include firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually obtain a registration token for a client (Android, iOS, web) before you can use pyfcm to send message to the client after obtaining the client's fcm registration token.