# Push notifications for mobile application

Tags: python, mobile, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am a beginner with mobile app development. I need to build a push notification for our existing mobile app.

- The current mobile app is built with HTML, backbone.js and jQuery for both Android and iOS. The backend is in Python.
- I found that there are applications like firebase communication messages, parser etc for the transport layer.
- I would like to know if I can use FCM with Python as backend.
- Also as I do not use the native mobile app, I also like to know if I can achieve push notifications using FCM in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would like to know if I can use FCM with Python as backend.**

- You may want to check [Python documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfcm/) which discussed regarding the use of pyfcm 1.2.2. Furthermore, this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405419/firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-in-python-with-pyfcm-client-registration) might also help.

**Also as I do not use the native mobile app , I also like to know if I can achieve push notifications using FCM in my app.**

- Actually, [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is used to implement push notifications for mobile devices and as mentioned, Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! Based from that statement, it's should be clear that it is possible to achieve push notifications using FCM.

I suggest that you please check [Firebase Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) and [Firebase - FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm) for more detailed information on the things that you can do with Firebase.